# Azure SQL Managed Instance

Tags: azure-sql-database

Has anybody here tried to make a read only table in Azure SQL or Azure SQL Managed Instance? I know with a box you create a filegroup, create the table in that filegroup and make that filegroup read-only, but since storage is different in Azure SQL...

Thanks,
Willie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can't create a read-only table directly, Azure SQL/Managed instance don't have this feature. But there are many ways can achieve that.

The easiest way is that we could create `INSTEAD OF Trigger` to make table read only.

An `INSTEAD OF TRIGGER` can also be defined on the table to restrict data manipulation on it by the users.

Here's the code example:

```
--Create sample table
CREATE TABLE FinancialTargetsForTrigger
(
ID int IDENTITY(1,1),
YearVal int,
QuarterVal int,
TargetVal int
)


--populate table with sample data
INSERT FinancialTargetsForTrigger
VALUES (2014,1,1789),
 (2014,2,3000),
 (2014,3,1100),
 (2014,4,2340),
 (2015,1,990),
 (2015,2,3420),
 (2015,3,2333),
 (2015,4,1123)


--create the INSTEAD OF Trigger to make table read only
 CREATE TRIGGER trg_FinancialTargetsForTrigger
 ON FinancialTargetsForTrigger
 INSTEAD OF INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE
 AS
 BEGIN
 RAISERROR ('This table is read only and cant be modified',16,1)
 END
```

I tested this code in my Azure SQL database and it works well.

[image]

For more details, you could reference this Microsoft document [SQLServer Tips: How To Make a Table Read Only in Database](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/31594.sqlserver-tips-how-to-make-a-table-read-only-in-database.aspx). It provide many ways for us.

Hope this helps

Comment: @jwb If my answer is helpful for you, please mark it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.